# Mongo Query Not Returning results VB

Tags: vb.net, mongodb

My profiler shows that the inner stage returns 1599 documents which is correct, but the outer one does not. I can't find the where the problem is.

Here is [a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jmxjbfm0/).

This is my filter, If I remove my equality filter it returns data. The same query in Compass returns data. Am I missing anything in my code?

```
Dim filter = Builders(Of BsonDocument).Filter.In(Of String)("CustomerNo", customerList.Select(Function(m) m.CustomerNo))
filter = filter And Builders(Of BsonDocument).Filter.Eq(Of Integer)("SupplierID", 410787)
Dim lsOH As List(Of BsonDocument) = collection.Find(filter).ToList()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I found the issue. Its the casing of SupplierID in the query. In the db SupplierId has "d" in small case. However I rewrote the code to be

```
 Dim filter = Builders(Of BsonDocument).Filter.And(
                                    Builders(Of BsonDocument).Filter.In(Of String)("CustomerNo", customerList.Select(Function(m) m.CustomerNo)),
                                    Builders(Of BsonDocument).Filter.Eq(Of Integer)("SupplierId", 410787))
```